# Woocommerce exclude specific categories products from related products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've added the following code to my child theme's function.php to exclude the category "workshops" from displaying Woocommerce Related Products.  How would I add in a 2nd category (ie. events) to this code?  Thanks.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'vn_remove_related_products' );
function vn_remove_related_products() {
  if ( is_product() && has_term( 'workshops', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp', 'vn_remove_related_products' );
function vn_remove_related_products() {
  if ( is_product() && has_term( array('workshops', 'events'), 'product_cat' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
  }
}
```

Function `has_term()` can pass first parameter as array with terms.